# How to automate filing a form as a user

Tags: posts, forms, curl

Sincere apologies if this has been asked and answered.  I'm a software developer with almost 0% experience in web.  I write C/C++ engineering applications.

I want to automate filling in a form on a wordpress website.  Currently I log in as admin, navigate to the page, and press edit on the content, and copy/past one url into a field on the form and publish.  The URL is to a vimeo.com video that is automatically uploaded to vimeo from other scripts I maintain.  It takes some time for the video to process/upload and the url for the form is not known for some time after I activate the processing of the video. Being able to automatically update the website from a script once the video is uploaded is ideal.

I was able to do this when the website was based on drupal simply through a sequence of curl commands from the command line.  I could log into my admin account, fetch the drupal page with the form, post a number of variables to change the field and submit with only 3-4 curl commands and some parsing code to read some context variables from the form returned by the previous curl get.

I've been trying to search the web and determine how this might be possible now that the website has been changed to wordpress, but haven't been able to find my way.  I was able to log into the website via curl with my credentials, fetch the form page to be filled, but couldn't figure out how to provide enough POST variables for it to find the context and accept the post to publish.

I've found things like wp-cli, wp-api, etc. that look promising, but seem to be more for maintaining a wordpress website, rather than simply editing a form on the site.  Even then my searching seems confused since most of what I find revolve around creating posts on a wordpress site, rather than posting to a form from a wordpress site.

Hoping someone can throw me a bone and point me in the right direction.